# Retrofit 2 request always failure - Kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I tried to learn about kotlin and retrofit 2 at the same time. I have this code.

I want to take all the /posts from [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts). But its always return a failure code. I'm very new in this, thanks

**Network interface**

```
interface APIService {

@GET("/posts")
fun getPosts(): Call<List<UserData>>
```

**POJO class**

```
open class UserData {

@SerializedName("userId")
@Expose
open var user_id: Int? = null

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
open var id: Int? = null

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
open var title: String? = null

@SerializedName("body")
@Expose
open var body: String? = null
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)

    service.getPosts().enqueue(object : Callback<List<UserData>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<UserData>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.d("RetrofitTest", t.toString())

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<UserData>>?, response: Response<List<UserData>>?) {
            Log.d("RetrofitTest", "onFailure")
        }

    })
}
}
```

Comment: In `onResponse` you have logged `onFailure`, are you sure you are not confused with that?

Comment: Oh my, Im sorry for my foolish mistake..

Answer (score 0):

in APIService  interface @GET("posts") insted of @GET("/posts")

Answer (score 0):

It always failed because the reason is the invalid URL. The mistake you have done is '/'. Either you can put the slash('/') in the base URL or at the starting of the Endpoint. In your case, the URL is like **"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com//posts"**. Which is invalid that's why your request getting failed. So just remove the '/' from the Endpoint.

**Make request interface like this:**

```
interface APIService {

   @GET("posts")
   fun getPosts(): Call<List<UserData>>

   }
```

Comment: I solved this, but I failed tried to log the data. How to log all the title sir?

Comment: just like this
val data = response?.body()
                Log.d("RetrofitTest", "responsennya ${data?.size}")

Comment: have you debugged response?